# Screen overlay in Notification

Tags: android, accessibility, overlay

I am looking for support in relation to overlay.

I have created an App to display a color filter over the screen (similar to the Twilight App), but I can not overlay over the notification area or on the lock screen as it stands now.

I see that the Twilight App asks for access to the accessibility feature to do this, but after the user grants this, how specifically is the App achieving the overlay over the notification area?